# It is possible to transform a Mysql select onto a Dataset with pure Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

i'm using Sqlite with local database storage for google chrome browser.

My query is like the next...
 var query = "SELECT * FROM items;";

In my table i have 6 field data

i already have a table in my html wiht id="example" and loading the head directly from the script as:

```js
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Date" },
            { "title": "Number" },
            { "title": "Name" },
            { "title": "Slogan" },
            { "title": "Description", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Amount", "class": "center" }
        ]
    });
```

What i need is the "Dataset" variable become the SQL arrays like

```
    var dataSet = [
    ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'],
    ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6'],
    ['field1','field2','field3','field4','field5','field6']
```

.
.etc
.etc 
.
    ];

Here's the example of what i want to use https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

All is local so i don't have PHP server to do that in other way.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: maybe check what alasql (http://alasql.org) could do for you.